# How to check Vagrant up progress

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-windows

I am using vagrant for first time.

I am trying to download a VM by running "vagrant up" command.
corresponding vagrant file is https://github.com/aalkilani/spark-kafka-cassandra-applying-lambda-architecture/tree/master/vagrant

i have a slow internet connection ..., its been around 1 hour i am not sure how much of download has happened .... few questions

1. How to check the % of download completed ( i know it will tell me when it reaches 20% ... but how to check % of downloaded )
2. Which temp directory does the vagrant download to ( if i have to stop download in between and resume tomorrow ... not sure if i need to cleanup or it will resume from where it left)

I am using Vagrant2.0.0 on windows7

looking forward to learn from your experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boxes are first downloaded from `~/.vagrant.d/tmp` so if you interrupt the download, it will remain here, if you have many unsuccessful downloads, you might want to clean this directory.

If download is in progress, you can follow the size of the file from this directory, if anything is moving or not.

once box file is fully downloaded, it will be installed in `~/.vagrant.d/boxes`

vagrant internally uses curl to download the box, you can use this tool or wget to download the particular box file and follow the progress directly from there.

For your particular case, the direct URL for the box is https://vagrantcloud.com/aalkilani/boxes/spark-kafka-cassandra-applying-lambda-architecture/versions/0.0.6/providers/virtualbox.box, you can download this file directly using your preferred tool. Once you have downloaded, you can install the box directly from the file.

Answer (score 2):

Acutally when you execute the `vagrant up` in the console, it will show the download processes.

But for your question, all the downloaded boxes are house in "C:\Users\USERNAME\.vagrant.d\boxes" folder.

Baically due to the poor connection, vagrant download the boxes very slow, so it is high recommand to download your base box in http://www.vagrantbox.es/ or https://app.vagrantup.com/boxes/search with the download tool, then you can add it by

`vagrant box add <title> <path_to_file>
vagrant init <title>
vagrant up`

Comment: (1) the folder is 416MB for past 15 mins , if i stop ( ctrl^C ) the process and restart it later ( by connecting to a different faster network in 5-6 hours ) will that work ? (2) how do i download it to vagrantbox.es ?

Comment: you can stop the vagrant process by ctrl+c, or close the console directly. download the boxes from vagrantbox.es, just copy the url in the table, and using any windows download tool.

Comment: i believe you are suggesting to copy url in table ... like https://abc and use it with "vagrant box add mytitle https://abc" ... but i am not sure which url to use ... not sure if its present at https://github.com/aalkilani/spark-kafka-cassandra-applying-lambda-architecture/blob/master/vagrant/Vagrantfile

Comment: you will find some urls with ".box", you can download it directly by the download tools.